# open directory in javascript - path issue

Tags: javascript, path, directory

I'm trying to create a js function in my project that when executed it does a very simple thing: it opens a directory in the browser
the standard usage is like this : 
_window.open('\myComputerName\c:\myPath')

unfortunately when calling the open function it actually tries to open the following path:

http:// LocalHost:8080 /MYAPP/pages/default/\myComputerName\c:\myPath
which of course doesn't work

any ideas how to work around this?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use some locally mapped resources you need to make them accessible via a virtual directory. If you are trying to open some file on any client machine, then you cannot do that. The browser does not have access to the file system.

So if you want to map local resources in a *virtual directory* open your IIS, then create a virtual directory and access it via localhost. E.g. map `c:\myPath` to the myPath virtual directory. Then myPath is accessible via `http://localhost[:port]/myPath`